# How to get a character from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list

I have a list of tuples like

```
[('EVTTIMESTAMP','timestamp'),('SUBSYTEMID','int'),('VRR ','string')]
```

How can I get the value `EVTTIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Have you tried `blockquote[0][0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you can loop through your list.

For example:

```
myList = [('EVTTIMESTAMP','timestamp'),('SUBSYTEMID','int'),('VRR ','string')] ;

for x in range(0,len(myList)):
    print(myList[x][0])
```

This will print:

```
EVTTIMESTAMP
SUBSYTEMID
VRR
```

Inside the loop you can put some logic to compare each element with the one you want to perform an operation on and only return the match.

For example:

```
for x in range(0,len(myList)):
    if myList[x][0] == "EVTTIMESTAMP":
        b = myList[x][0]
        ##do something with b
```

If you know the exact position of the item, then you can just call it like:

`b = myList[0][0]` etc...

For example:

`print(myList[0][0])` will print: `EVTTIMESTAMP`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

for getting all the 2nd value of the tuples you can use

```
a = [('EVTTIMESTAMP','timestamp'),('SUBSYTEMID','int'),('VRR ','string')]
[x[1] for x in a]
```

for getting specific value of "EVTTIMESTAMP" u can use if condition

```
[x[1] for x in a if x[0] == 'EVTTIMESTAMP']
```